# Only display part of JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have the following JSON...

```
var json = [{"Name":" Jim", "ID":"23", "Age": "0"},{"Name":" Bob", "ID":"53", "Age": "0"}]
```

How would I only display the propety `Name` in an updated JSON? For example, I would want the JSON file to be transformed into this:

```
var json2 = [{"Name":" Jim"},{"Name":" Bob"}]
```

Comment: Neither of those are valid JSON.  You're missing `[....]` around each one.

Comment: Is your goal to transform the JSON file so that it's an array of objects which only contain the name, or to display only the name property of each object?

Comment: Can have 30 different properties and only display one....not clear what real objective is here

Comment: javascript where? in browser or node server? Can't change file in browser

Answer (score 0):

```
var json2 = json.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    Name: obj.Name
  }
});
```

If you're writing this in an environment with lambdas (eg, TypeScript) then it can be done in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Pluck name from each object and return an array of names

```
json.map((obj) => (obj.name)) // = ["Bob", "Tom", "Jerry"]
```

Pluck name from each object, and return an array of objects with a name key and value

```
json.map((obj) => ({name: obj.name})) // = [{name: "Bob"}, {name: "Tom"}, {name: "Jerry"}]
```

Ref:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = json.map(({ Name }) => ({ Name }));
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/burovavori/edit?js,console)